# Deriving joint PMF of geometric distribution

Tags: statistics, random-variables

> Suppose $Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_n$ is a random sample from the geometric distribution with probability of success,p. Derive the joint probability mass function (PMF); justify your answer.

Is the answer to this simply multiplying n geometric distributions PMFs? Or is there a special trick with re: being from a random sample? I obviously know how to derive i.i.d. joint distributions, but am a little confused here. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I think no trick, just a product of independent distributions since elements of a random sample are independent.